# how can in make that the icons are almost at the right edge of the "container" div but are aligned vertically

Tags: html, css

How can I make all the `<i class="bi bi-chevron-right flecha"></i>` are almost at the right edge of the "container" div but are aligned vertically?

[image: example]

I want to achieve something similar to the image above. You can see that all the arrows that point to the right are almost on the right side but are aligned vertically.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  font-size: 24px;
}

body {}

#contenedor {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 700px;
  height: 850px;
  background-color: wheat;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

img {
  width: 60px;
}

button {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.opciones {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

i {
  font-size: 32px;
}

#titulo {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

a {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.flecha {
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>mi cuenta</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/micuenta.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.2/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="contenedor">
    <h1 id="titulo">mi cuenta</h1>
    <div class="opciones" id="usuario">
      <button><img src="/img/seguridad.png" alt=""></button>
      <a href="">inicio de sesion y seguridad</a><i class="bi bi-chevron-right flecha "></i>
      <!--cambiar informacion personal del usuario-->
    </div>
    <div class="opciones" id="pedidos">
      <button><img src="/img/pedidos.png" alt=""></button>
      <a href="">mis pedidos</a><i class="bi bi-chevron-right flecha"></i>
      <!--todos procesando enviado entregado  cancelados por el usuario -->
    </div>
    <div class="opciones" id="paquetes">
      <button><i class="bi bi-geo-alt-fill"></i></button>
      <a href="">direccion</a><i class="bi bi-chevron-right flecha "></i>
      <!--direccion de entrega de paquetes-->
    </div>
    <div class="opciones" id="metodospago">
      <button> <i class="bi bi-credit-card"></i></button>
      <a href="">metodos de pago</a><i class="bi bi-chevron-right  flecha"></i>
      <!--tarjetas de credito del usuario-->
    </div>
    <div class="opciones" id="ayuda">
      <button><i class="bi bi-question-octagon"></i></button>
      <a href="">servicio al cliente</a><br><i class="bi bi-chevron-right  flecha"></i>
      <!--ayuda/ pqr-->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="" alt="alt">
  <div class="text">
     Some text
  </div>
  <i class="bi bi-chevron-right flecha"></i>
</div>
```

```css
.parent{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
img{
  width: 20%;
}
.text{
  width: 60%;
}
.bi{
  width: 20%;
}
```

You can see `display: flex; align-items: center;` in `.parent` class, that will make the inner elements vertically center.